# GeoJson with multiple types to C# class

Tags: c#, .net-core, geojson

I have a GeoJson which contains polygons and multipolygons, from with I need to select 1 polygon based on an Id. But I am not able to deserialize it because I cannot set up a C# class to bind to it.
A polygon has structure: `List<List<List<double>>>`
Whereas a multipolygon is: `List<List<List<List<double>>>>`
And I am using System.Text.Json.
Is there any way to achieve this?

Sample GeoJson:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              7.6,
              47.4
            ],...
          ]
         ]
       },
  "properties": {
   "id":1
  }
 },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "multipolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
           [
            [
              7.4,
              47.5
            ]
           ]
          ]
         ],...
```

Comment: You have perfect case example of json parsing via Newtonsoft.JSON library. What makes you life easy is type node in geometry object, and you can use that, to determine how parse coordinates correctly. Other scenario would be just use single List<List<List<List<double>>>> model, and then deserialize string to object with [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayConverter<...>))] markup. System.Text.Json is not as powerful, and you would more than likely write parser yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the following json:

```
{
  "type": "polygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [7.6,47.4],[2,3]
    ]
  ]
}
```

The following class maps it:

```
public class X {
   public List<List<List<decimal>>> coordinates {get; set;}
}
```

Let's test it:

```
var x = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<X>(json);
Console.WriteLine(x.coordinates[0][0][0]);
```

Success! It printed:

```
7.6
```

Comment: Yes, but my data has polygons as well as multipolygons. The above class X will not work for multipolygon :(

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Newtonsoft.Json NuGet package. Once you parse the JSON into a JObject, you can simply use LINQ to find the one(s) that you need.

```
// if you need just one
jObject.Children().Where((jO) => jO["id"] == 1).First();

// if you need to loop over ones with the same id
foreach(JObject j in jObject.Children().Where((jO) => jO["id"] == 1))
{

}
```